# Jinja2 how to ouptput javascript string value

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a html page runs with flask framework and I use jinja2 to ouptput partial content:

```
<script>function test(str){ alert(str) }</script>

{% set s = 'Hello! Jinja~' %}
<a href='#' onclick='test({{s}})'>click me</a>
```

How could the page alert

> Hello! Jinja~

while the link is clicked?

Current the html ouput just like:

```
<a href="#" onclick="test(Hello! Jinja~)">click me</a>
```

This causes javascript error...

The variable s is got from db or other handling before page render and not a constant string!

Thanks much...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surround the Jinja expression in quotes so that it is treated as a string in JavaScript.

```html
{% set s = 'Hello! Jinja~' %}
<a href='#' onClick="alert('{{ s }}')">click me</a>
```